# Magento Go - jQuery works only on product details page

Tags: jquery, magento

I added some custom jQuery to the footer static block as documented on Magento Go website:

```
(function($) {
alert("lol");
})(jQuery);
```

And this only works on product page. On every other page on the website I get

```
jQuery is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

})(jQuery);
```

from Firebug. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't loading jQuery correctly on all pages. That is why you are getting the 'jQuery is not defined' error.

I'm not as familiar with Magento Go -- so you will need to find out why product pages are including the script but other pages aren't. In a non-hosted solution, this would mean editing a [layout].xml file. Not sure if that helps you.

Comment: They have different javascript on product page which references jQuery, while on other pages it doesn't. I guess I'll have to go without it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but seeing as it wasn't answered I thought I'd give my solution.  This was frustrating to figure out.

To clarify the issue, Magento Go has a base version of jQuery it uses.  However, it doesn't load the library on every page.  In my case, it only loads on the product page.  You can add your own version, and run it in noConflict(), by adding the code to the header section in the design configuration.  However, if you want to only load jquery if you need it, only on pages where Magento Go didn't already load it, here's how you do that:

Create a static block, and put in the following code:

> Code originally found at
>   http://forum.jquery.com/topic/loading-jquery-if-undefined and modified
>   for my needs

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
/******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src", "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js")
    script_tag.onload = customJQ; 
    script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { //Same thing but for IE
        if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') customJQ();
    } //onreadystatechange.function
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script_tag);
    } else {
        customJQ();
} //if.jQuery

function customJQ() {
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        ... your query here ... 
    });
}
// ]]></script>
```

Then create a frontend app that loads this block on all pages, and put it in the "Page Bottom" block reference.  I put it at the bottom in order to give Magento Go a chance to load the script, this might not be necessary.

If jquery is already loaded, it will just run your script.  If it's not loaded, jquery will be loaded and your script executed once loading is complete.